# Apple remote desktop alternative possible?

Tags: remote-desktop

The admin has set up an xserve which I can use to connect to its desktop using ARD. However my ARD seems to be crashing when I try to control the xserve. I can view it perfectly but only when I try to control the app crashes.

is there any way to use another app to connect to this xserve? I have no idea how the xserve has set up the remote desktop, all I know is that I'm supposed to use ARD. I have admin access to the xserve through ssh but I need to be able to view the screen because I need to use the open windows on the xserve.

I know I could ask the admin but I'm working at night and I need to fix some problem urgently and there is no way to ask the admin within the next few hours.

Thanks.

Comment: by the way I'm on lion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Mac's built in Screen Sharing app. You can browse to the server in the Finder, or run `/System/Library/CoreServices/Screen Sharing.app` and enter the server's IP or hostname.